# Returning random String in Array per button press

Tags: android, arrays, string, random

I have the following situation:

I have an array with 245 `String` items. Now I have a `Button` which gives me a random `String` from the array when clicked. But then, I get repetition like after one string, the previous string comes. How to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Resources res = getResources();

    titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.title_array); 

    String q = titles[rgenerator.nextInt(titles.length)];

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(q);

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert your words array to arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(titles));
```

Then create another list which holds the words that have already printed

```
ArrayList<String> usedList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then when you get a word just remove it from wordlist and move it to usedlist

```
String s = wordsList.get(rgenerator.nextInt(wordsList.size()));
wordsList.remove(s);
usedList.add(s);
```

Comment: No I got just one title, then another title, maybe an other title and then the title at the beginning.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to convey, can you please elaborate